# Can I say a Constructor is a Method?

Tags: oop, methods, constructor, terminology

I wonder if can I say that a **constructor** is a special case of a **method**?

Comment: A bit too vague. Define method.

Comment: Dirkgently, I think the meaning of "method" in programming / OOP is pretty clear, why do you find it vague?

Comment: @dirk, your comment is a bit too vague.  Define vague.  (Seriously, the question is well-defined).

Comment: +1 to pavel :) If the question is vague, there would not be clear answers below.

Comment: IME, the term method has multiple definitions.

Comment: @dirkgently: i think you are perfectly right. If we define method as a subroutine associated with class/object then constructor is a method. But if we define method as a function then requirement for function to return a value might be the source of problems.

Comment: @kemiisto: Isn't the *whole point* of a constructor to return a newly constructed object?

Comment: @Gan: The accepted answer "You can say anything" is as good as saying that the question is vague (and I mean absolutely no offense to bmargulies).

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: hmmm... Primary task of constructor is initialization the object's data members. For example, in Java (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) we can say that the new keyword followed by a call to a constructor returns a newly created not the constructor itself.

Comment: @kemisto: I would say that initialization is the initializer's job, not the constructor's. After all, there is a reason, the initializer is called "initializer" and the constructor is called "constructor". If the constructor's job were initialization, it would probably be called "initializer".

Comment: @dirkgently and @kemiisto: To me, method is equivalent to subroutine and function, and subroutine is a type of function that returns nothing. That's why I don't find the question vague.

Comment: @dirk no offense taken. My view is that, without more context, the answer to the question is 'MU!' or 'Yes' if you prefer. There are a number of possible elaborations on the questions that would result in 'no', or a more nuanced 'yes'. For example, are we talking about a situation like Java where the environment allows creation without construction?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can say anything. Whether anyone will disagree with you depends on the context. Some language communities and standards define things that way.

More elaborately, it depends on what you mean by a 'method.' In C++, for example, one way to analyze the creation process is to say that it consists of a call to an operator new (perhaps just placement) followed by a call to a constructor *method*. From an implementation standpoint, a constructor looks, walks, and quacks like a method. In some compilers, you can even invoke one explicitly.

From a more theoretical viewpoint, someone might claim that constructors are some distinctive species. However, there is no single, true, privileged conceptual model of methods, constructors, or purple unicorns.

Gosh this is all subjective.

Comment: "You can say anything." But remember "Anything you say can and will be used against you in a court of law." =)

Comment: @kemiisto +1 for your comment, as I don't see a real value of the chosen answer :-) I think the other answers would together render into a pretty good and elaborate answer.

Comment: @Ondrej Tucny: and I don't see a value of the question itself.

Comment: @kemiisto If you don't think as a user of a programming language, then you're right and it makes not much sense to ask such a question. However, if you study programming language design, it's quite a fundamental question with many aspects.

Comment: +1 to Ondrej, I agree with you ("don't see a real value of the chosen answer" :)

Comment: @ond if you want to have an intellectual discussion about this, you would need (a) to specify the terms of reference and (b) take it to the new Programmers.Stackexchange.com site.

Comment: @bmargulies my comment applied when your answer didn't state much more than “You can say anything.” I don't think the topic needs to be discusses any further.

Answer (score 15):

You could say so, just as you can say that *a **human** is a special case of **animal***, however in most contexts mentioning *animals* implies *non-human animals* and mentioning *methods* implies *non-constructor methods*.

Answer (score 9):

Technically, a constructor **usually is** a method. Whether it really is or is not depends largely on the particular environment. For example, in .NET constructors are methods called actually after an object is created. However, it's also possible to create an object without having a constructor called right after.

**Update:** Regarding .NET, or the Common Language Infrastructure to be more precise, ECMA 335, section 8.9.6.6 Constructors states:

> New values of an object type are created via constructors. Constructors shall be instance methods, defined via a special form of method contract, which defines the method contract as a constructor for a particular object type.

Comment: How can you say it usually is a method when it doesn't have a return type?

Comment: Providing a method is a named bunch of executable code (in a very simplistic sense), why a method should have a “return type”?

Comment: Technically, it depends on context a lot. E.g., in Java there's clear difference between terms 'constructor' and 'method' (don't know about C#). Also, here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: @Nikita Actually the common meaning of a 'method' is the 'code' in the 'object = data + code' equation :-) In programming language design it's useful to have one single abstraction for a "named buch of executable code", and the 'method' paradigm fit quite well. From that, treating constructors as special methods is quite obvious. Note that all the quotes and apostrophes are quite necessare here in this discussion as most terms are not defined properly and in the context of a specific OO programming language / abstract OOP term-set.

Comment: every method has a return type.

Comment: @Woot4Moo In what language? I think not-so-absolutist claims are appropriate here. For example, in CLI EMCA 335 in section 8.6.1.5 Method signatures says about “return types” that “A method signatures is composed of … a type signature for the result value, **if one is produced**.”

Comment: once again look at the definition of void

Comment: @Woor4Moo I'm not arguing void is a type. But you are obviously not getting the point, at least in respect the situation in the .NET world, because in .NET a constructor **is** a method **by definition**. See my updated answer above.

Answer (score 2):

I think a constructor is too special to be called a method

- It doesn't return anything
- It modifies the object **before** the object is initialized
- It cannot call itself (imagine that)

blah blah blah

There might be difference between languages, but I don't think I'm going as far as calling a constructor "special method".

Comment: you can't modify something before it exists

Comment: hmm right, "initialized" is a better word

Comment: Constructor does not return anything. Methods can also be declared to return nothing (void in C++).

Comment: void is a return type whereas a constructor does not have a return type

Comment: @Woot4Moo: do you know that there are couple of programming languages (VB.NET, Pascal , Fortran, Ada, ...) which distinguish between "functions" or "function subprograms", which provide an explicit return value to the calling program, and "subroutines" or "procedures", which do not? Subroutines which doesn't return anything is so typical in such languages.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: yes, void is a return type. What I was trying to convey is that a constructor is similar to a void method (both do not return anything).

Comment: I think it is indeed a method, just a special one. First, It has no return type. But that's not completely true. It returns the object it creates, it's just not that obvious in the code. Then it creates an object, modifies it and points to the created object when it's called. LBNL you can call the constructor inside itself. It just doesn't make much sense, unless you want to create objects with optional parameters but you don't want to overload the constructor

Answer (score 2):

In languages that have constructors, you can usually think of a constructor as a special case of a factory method. (Note: I don't mean the GoF Factory Method Software Design Pattern, I'm just talking about *any* class method that creates new instances.) Usually, this "special casing" generally takes the form of annoying restrictions (e.g. in Java, you can only call the parent constructor at the beginning of the constructor), which is why even in languages that *do* have constructors, you often end up using or writing factory methods anyway.

So, if constructors are basically factory methods with restrictions, there is really no need to have them both, and thus many languages simply get rid of constructors. Examples include Objective-C, Ruby, Smalltalk, Self, Newspeak, ECMAScript/JavaScript, Io, Ioke, Seph and many others.

In Ruby, the closest thing to a constructor is the method [`Class#allocate`](http://RDoc.Info/docs/ruby-core/1.9.2/Class#allocate-instance_method), which simply allocates an empty object and sets that object's class pointer. Nothing more. Since such an empty object is obviously unusable, it needs to initialized. Per convention, this initialization is performed by `#initialize`. As a convenience, because it is cumbersome to always have to remember to both allocate and initialize (as any Objective-C developer can probably attest), there is a helper method called `Class#new`, which looks something like this:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    obj = allocate
    obj.initialize(*args, &block)

    return obj
  end
end
```

This allows you to replace this:

```
foo = Foo.allocate
foo.initialize(bar)
```

With this:

```
foo = Foo.new(bar)
```

It is important to note that there is nothing special about any of these methods. Well, with one exception: `Class#allocate` obviously has to be able to set the class pointer and to allocate memory, which is something that is not possible in Ruby. So, this method has to somehow come from outside the system, which e.g. in MRI means that it is written in C, not Ruby. But that only concerns the implementation. There are no special dispatch rules, no special override rules. It's just a method like any other that can e.g. call `super` whereever, whenever and how often it wants and can return what it wants.

Answer (score 0):

"Special" is the magic word here. There's absolutely nothing wrong with calling a constructor a special method, but what "special" implies can vary depending on the language.

In most cases, "special" means they can't return values or be called as a method without creating a new object. But there are always exceptions: a prime example is JavaScript, where a constructor is no different from a normal function, it *can* return its own values and it *can* be called either as a constructor or as a simple function.

Answer (score 0):

@Tom Brito, personally I would agree with you that a constructor is a *special case of method*.

Also, see below:

> A constructor in a class is a special type of subroutine called at the creation of an object.
>
> ... A constructor resembles an instance method, but it differs from a method in that it never has an explicit return-type...

Source:
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29)

Also, you may read my comments on others' comment (woot4moo, phunehehe).

Answer (score 0):

At least in vb.net, constructors can have a non-standard control flow.  If the first statement of a constructor is a call to New (of either the same type or a base type), the sequence of events will be: (1) perform the call; (2) initialize all the fields associated with the type; (3) finish handling the rest of the constructor.  No normal method has that sort of control flow.  This control flow makes it possible to do things like pass constructor parameters to field initializers of a derived type, if the base type is written to allow such.